# Transpose Pandas DataFrame by select Datetime values in rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Timestamp              Value
2017-01-03 00:00:00    13.05
2017-01-03 00:01:00    13.70
2017-01-03 00:02:00    13.07
...
2017-01-27 09:57:00    13.46
2017-01-27 09:58:00    13.43
2017-01-27 09:59:00    13.41
```

How can I transpose it so as to have a single row per day, and columns for specific hours and minutes (say from 0 to 10 hours) (there are no seconds in the Timestamp, they are all zeros).

So far, I can successfully use `df[df.index.time < datetime.time(10,0)]` to select the rows for each day below hour 10. But if I subsequently do `.T` to transpose that selection, then the entire DataFrame gets transposed into one very long row. How can I perform that `.T` operation on batches of rows for each distinct day from the Timestamp? (and also possibly put each Day value in the first column of the transposed dataset?

I would rather avoid custom code and looping, as the dataset is large, so something built-in is much preferred!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the index to be a multi-index of date and then time followed by an `unstack`

```
df.set_index(
    [df.Timestamp.dt.date, df.Timestamp.dt.time]
).Value.rename_axis([None] * 2).unstack()
```

[image]

Comment: Just adding slight variation for if the index is already a datetime. Note that 'Value' is the name of the column in the dataframe that you want transposed: `df.set_index([df.index.date, df.index.time]).Value.rename_axis([None] * 2).unstack()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) method:

```
In [214]: df.assign(d=df.Timestamp.dt.date, t=df.Timestamp.dt.time) \
            .pivot_table(index='d', columns='t', values='Value', fill_value=0) \
            .rename_axis(None, 1)
Out[214]:
            00:00:00  00:01:00  00:02:00  09:57:00  09:58:00  09:59:00
2017-01-03     13.05      13.7     13.07      0.00      0.00      0.00
2017-01-27      0.00       0.0      0.00     13.46     13.43     13.41
```

PS but I would prefer @piRSquared's solution as it's more elegant...